# What is the function of bitwise & in this statement?

Tags: c#, algorithm, bitwise-operators, bitwise-and

I have been reading about an [implementation](http://www.bluh.org/code-the-diamond-square-algorithm/) of the diamond-square algorithm in C# that wraps around to create seamless textures. To calculate the next point, an average is taken of  four sample points arranged in a square or a diamond. If a sample point lies of the edge of the texture, it is wrapped around to the other side. This wrapping appears to be done using the following method:

```
public double sample(int x, int y)
{
    return values[(x & (width - 1)) + (y & (height - 1)) * width];
}
```

A little bit of research tells me this is a bitwise operator. I have not used them before, and the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation) was not enlightening. Could someone explain what the `&` operator is doing in this method?

EDIT: The texture dimensions are always powers of two

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's for the "wrapping". Assuming `width` and `height` are powers of two (otherwise it doesn't work, so that had better be true), `x & (width - 1)` is mostly equivalent to `x % width`, except that it also works for negative `x` (whereas `x % width` with a negative `x` would have a negative result) and is almost certainly faster.

Or to put it visually with an example, say `width = 64` and `x = 64+12 = 76`, then

```
x       = 00000000 00000000 00000000 01001100
w       = 00000000 00000000 00000000 01000000
w-1     = 00000000 00000000 00000000 00111111
x & w-1 = 00000000 00000000 00000000 00001100 = 12
```

As you can see from the form of `w-1`, the operation `x & w-1` is like taking only the bottom bits of `x`, assuming of course that `w` is still a power of two. So the bits with weights 64 and multiples of 64 are removed, just as a true "modulo 64" operation would (which is not `%` in C# if you are working with signed integers, that's a remainder).